# Router version issue in angularcli

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

@angular/cli: 1.4.9
node: 6.11.0
os:   win32 x64
npm : 3.10.10

the rxjs version in package.json file is "rxjs": "^5.4.2".

The same configuration is working on my collegues machine. without giving this error

import statement is like below :

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

Constructor statement is like below :

constructor( private router: Router) {

Routing statement is like below :

this.router.navigate(['policy']);

I am getting below error while using router in .ts  file to navigate from one html5  page to another.

Error coming is like below :

Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence
EmptyError: no elements in sequence
    at new EmptyError (EmptyError.js:28)
    at FirstSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/first.js.FirstSubscriber._complete (first.js:154)
    at FirstSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._complete (mergeMap.js:150)

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely an issue with the current version of rxjs
See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3151 for details.

// DLDR: Revert your rxjs to max. 5.5.2, that should do the trick

Comment: the rxjs version which I could see in package.json file is "rxjs": "^5.4.2"., which is already lower than 5.5.2. Still I am getting the issue. Please Guide.